# Right way to seed MongoDB for automated testing with Karate

Tags: mongodb, junit, continuous-integration, automated-tests, karate

I'm building an automated API testbed and I've chosen Karate for the job. Too bad its engine is written for a Java ecosystem, where the community support for mongoDB technology is not that strong as for NodeJS

Since I need to seed/cleanup DBs In QA environment to execute tests, but I just have a seeding script made with NodeJS and a specific library, so now I have two opportunites

1. Keep using a NodeJS init script where my DB is populated before running Karate tests
2. Use a Java seeding library that enables fixture loading from files (ex. JSON) or from DB dumps and execute the seed before each feature with JUnit hooks

Both alternatives should enable devs/qas to build multiple fixtures and select which one is suited for a certain set of feature tests. For instance, in the scenario #1 i could write a sh script that does

```
npm run seed
mvn clean test
```

But it lacks control from qa on which data to load (unless you don't specify it in this shell script, which means that must be updated often and must "know" which features are implemented and when to run them). The other downside is that CI server must have nodeJS installed and the pipeline configuration must know it, and CI servers should not have many tools installed on

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the Java interop, it will be very easy for you to call an OS command from Karate.

```
* def FileUtils = Java.type('com.intuit.karate.FileUtils')
* def runtime = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()
* def exec = function(cmd){ return FileUtils.toString(runtime.exec(cmd).getInputStream()) }
* def result = exec('my-nodejs-cli-command')
```

And you have all the env-switching flexibility, for e.g. you can use variables as the `exec()` argument.

Doesn't MongoDB have some ways of calling it via REST. Because Karate happens to be good at making REST requests :)

Comment: thank you! so what you suggest is to run my seed script in a separate process and have nodejs installed in my environment! it would be very nice if I could write nodejs scripts directly in karate javascript functions, mostly to leverage package management

Comment: @CarmineIngaldi this may actually happen later this year because of GraalVM integration. but not right now, sorry: https://twitter.com/ptrthomas/status/1095346113027092480