# Get user console input during a karate test execution

Tags: maven, automated-tests, cucumber, karate, junit4

I'm working in some tets cases, in some of them I need to get a dinamic token which I only can get with a phisical device in a manual process, this token is one-use only (when the request gets processed the token is no longer usable), so I need to stop the execution, get the token using the console and put it into my request. Right now I am using a simple java code with the Scanner class (something really standar) to get the console input, but at the time that the test is running when the execution stops to get the input I'm not able to put anything in console. I'm running my test whit maven commands (using karate framework as I mention on the title).

Rigth now I found a kind of solution using the Intellij runner modifying the VM options with `-Deditable.java.test.console=true`, but I still want to know if is possible to run the test and get the console input when I run the tests with maven.

To leave things clear, I'm using Karate 0.9.0 (I know that is a really old version but I can not use a newer one or even a release version because of client requirements), Junit4, Java 8 and maven 3.8.1.

Comment: really hard to support an old version :( for example if you use the CLI helpers in karate, you can listen to log output: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/cli/README.md - if it helps we are considering a service to help teams upgrade Karate versions you can reach out at https://www.karatelabs.io/support

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Karate have excellent CLI support, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/cli/README.md

What I suggest is this, write a program in any other language and with [a little bit of Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675755/143475) you should be able to invoke that via a shell / OS command and capture console output or even pop up a Java swing dialog or equivalent. That other program you write can even write to a file if that helps. Then getting the data you need and proceeding should be easy. You can look at the [Karate code](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.1/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/shell/Command.java#L342) for inspiration.